# Appending a Line between a start and end date

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, gantt-chart

Basically I am using D3 to create a chart based off a gantt. I have a .json file which contains my data and was able to create my x-y scales displaying the appropriate information. This issue I am having is that I want the lines to extend between a start and end date for each of the 15 items in the array, all of which contain a name, start date and end date. When I fire up the chart the information displays but it just shows a solid line starting at the y axis and it extends until it reaches an individuals start date.

While attempting to remedy the situation, I realized that by adding todays date as a new item in the array under startDate, that any of the items dated to today do exactly as I want them to while the others do not. I am not sure what could be causing it but speculating that maybe it has to do with how the dates are parsing? Totally at a loss as I am still new to d3.

```
// employment.json 
[
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 1",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2013-09-05",
      "endDate": "2019-08-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 2",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2013-09-05",
      "endDate": "2018-10-31"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 3",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2013-11-05",
      "endDate": "2014-03-03"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 4",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2014-05-09",
      "endDate": "2015-04-06"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 5",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2014-12-01",
      "endDate": "2019-08-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 6",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2015-04-20",
      "endDate": "2016-10-18"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 7",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2016-05-05",
      "endDate": "2019-07-31"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 8",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2016-11-07",
      "endDate": "2017-05-12"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 9",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2017-09-18",
      "endDate": "2019-08-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 10",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2018-01-11",
      "endDate": "2018-09-20"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 11",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2018-04-17",
      "endDate": "2018-07-24"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 12",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2018-07-04",
      "endDate": "2018-08-30"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 13",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2018-07-09",
      "endDate": "2019-08-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 14",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2019-01-16",
      "endDate": "2019-08-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "Placeholder 15",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2019-04-01",
      "endDate": "2019-08-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "Total Time",
      "position": "Occupation 1",
      "startDate": "2013-09-05",
      "endDate": "2019-08-01"
     }
  ]

// app.js

var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 80, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 560 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#employment_history")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json('json/employment.json', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      return console.warn(error);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width ])
        .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.startDate }, 
data.map(function(d) { return d.endDate })))
        .padding(0.2);
    svg.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
        .style("text-anchor", "end");

    var y = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([ 0, height ])
        .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }))
        .padding(2);
      svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  // Lines
  svg.selectAll("myLine")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d.startDate); })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d.endDate); })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return y(d.name); })
      .attr("stroke", "orange")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  })
```

no errors showing in console, it provides a chart that starts at the Y axis and extends to the start date, rather than starting at the start date and connecting to the end date.

An example of what I am trying to accomplish and what I was following to create this is this: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/lollipop_cleveland.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the **wrong scales**.

The main problem here is the x axis, which should use a **time scale**, not a band scale. So, let's see the necessary changes:

First, parse the dates in the data array:

```
const parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.startDate = parse(d.startDate);
  d.endDate = parse(d.endDate);
});
```

Then, set the time scale, calculating the domain based on the dates:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.startDate
  }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.endDate
  })]);
```

Finally, your y scale should be a **point** scale, not a band scale:

```
var y = d3.scalePoint()
  .range([0, height])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .padding(0.5);
```

And here is the working code (in a smaller SVG):

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Placeholder 1",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2013-09-05",
    "endDate": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 2",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2013-09-05",
    "endDate": "2018-10-31"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 3",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2013-11-05",
    "endDate": "2014-03-03"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 4",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2014-05-09",
    "endDate": "2015-04-06"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 5",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2014-12-01",
    "endDate": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 6",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2015-04-20",
    "endDate": "2016-10-18"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 7",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2016-05-05",
    "endDate": "2019-07-31"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 8",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2016-11-07",
    "endDate": "2017-05-12"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 9",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2017-09-18",
    "endDate": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 10",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2018-01-11",
    "endDate": "2018-09-20"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 11",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2018-04-17",
    "endDate": "2018-07-24"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 12",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2018-07-04",
    "endDate": "2018-08-30"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 13",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2018-07-09",
    "endDate": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 14",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2019-01-16",
    "endDate": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "Placeholder 15",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2019-04-01",
    "endDate": "2019-08-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "Total Time",
    "position": "Occupation 1",
    "startDate": "2013-09-05",
    "endDate": "2019-08-01"
  }
];

var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 80,
    left: 100
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.startDate = parse(d.startDate);
  d.endDate = parse(d.endDate);
});

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.startDate
  }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.endDate
  })]);

svg.append('g')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
  .style("text-anchor", "end");

var y = d3.scalePoint()
  .range([0, height])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  }))
  .padding(0.5);

svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

// Lines
svg.selectAll("myLine")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return x(d.startDate);
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return x(d.endDate);
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return y(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return y(d.name);
  })
  .attr("stroke", "orange")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much for such a well thought answer- I know my explanation was confusing so thank you for navigating that mess as well!